# Azure SQL Database の接続時について

Tags: sql-server, sql-azure

ユーザーがアプリケーションデータベースを通してOracle Databaseに接続する時、最初にidとパスワードの２つが認証として要求されるような仕組みですが、Azure SQL Database(尚、認証の仕組みはSQL認証に設定しているものとする)でもアプリケーションデータベースを通してAzure SQL Databaseに接続する時、最初にidとパスワードが認証として要求される仕組みですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。感謝します。今の状況でもう三つほど質問したいです。websurferさんはそれをどうやって知りましたか？本で勉強して知ったならその本を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: もう一つはそのデータベースとの接続が確立後、データベースからデータを取り出し、アプリケーションで処理するためにデータを送受信する際に傍受されたくないため、通信を暗号化したいです。何か一般的な方法はありませんか？

Comment: そしてもう一つはそのSQL認証には接続文字列の情報でパスできると思います。この接続文字列をアプリケーションに持たせておくのはセキュリティ面でいいのかわるいのかすらわからないです。アプリケーションをセキュリティ上保護する一般的な方法は何かありませんか？そして接続文字列自体を保護する方法は何かありませんか？